# Why controller as is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've forked some code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HoKXmLSoDP6NODeZVT80?p=preview) in AngularJS and am trying to rewrite it with [John Papa's conventions](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) in mind.

I get an error:

> Argument 'testCtrl as ctrl' is not a function, got undefined

Why ?

```
(function() {

    angular.module('Test', [])
        .controller('testCtrl', testCtrl)
        .directive('testDirective', testDirective);


    function testCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.options = {};

        vm.callMe = function() {
            console.log("called from crontroller");
            vm.options.method1("something");
        };

    }

    function testDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                options: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.options.method1 = function(message) {
                    console.log("called from crontroller: " + message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: In index.html the line using the code is : <body ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">

Comment: you're using angular 1.0.2, maybe too old?

Comment: @KevinB answer is the right one, if you update the version it works.

Comment: @KevinB please add it as an answer so I can accept is as the correct one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Angular used in your plunkr doesn't support ControllerAs, update it to a newer version.